# Roslyn : Get Current Project / Get Current Doc that is selected

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm developing a code gen (VSIX) for my team and I'm intendedly using Roslyn as a fundamental engine after I have struggling with VSIX extensibility framework.

My code gen is currently able generate a new csproj for the solution and able to churn out boilerplate code base based on Templating project from VSIX extensibility. As ambitious I am, I'm trying not to rely on static templating project and use Roslyn to churn out the code instead.

My solution has a list of folders and each folder has a list of csproj.

My Question 1 is I'm trying to use Roslyn Workspace API to detect the current document (.cs) that has been open in code editor or am trying to get the current doc id of the selected cs file I right click from the solution explorer.

I have tried to use AdhocWorkspace which so far have failed as I'm not able to get any.

Question 2: If I were to use AdhocWorkspace, am I able to change the default namespace in the csproj properties? Or was it not part of the functionalities in Roslyn Workspace API at the moment?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're using VS2015, you need to use the [`VisualStudioWorkspace`](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/). This is what VS uses under the hood. You can use [`GetOpenDocumentIds()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Workspace_Editor.cs,356559a2f4bb0d36). You should also consider that multiple documents might be opened at once. (eg. Split panes)

Comment: @JoshVarty: Doesn't that API also return inactive tabs?

Comment: Yeah it does. There's no notion of "latest opened tab" in the Workspace layer (as far as I can tell) so it probably requires [`GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContext`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/TextExtensions.cs,7d8ce0f29a31ba83). `SourceTextContainer` can be found from an `IWpfTextView` or `ITextBuffer` via: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text/Extensions.cs

Comment: @JoshVarty Aside of using VisualStudioWorkspace, is there a way of getting Document obj by right clicking on a cs file in a csproj?

Comment: If you're not using VisualStudioWorkspace, you'd have to rely on matching them up based on filepath, but you'd have to consider things like shared projects and shared documents. There can be multiple `Document` objects for a given C# file on disk.

Comment: @SimonLoh: You need to use VisualStudioWorkspace.  But you also need to use VS APIs to get TextBuffers or HierarchyItems from selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #1 some code I have to do the same thing. I am doing stuff with the cursor so I'm going through caretPosition (cursor). There are other ways but the gist is the same, get the current textview the go from that to Roslyn.

You will need to install `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text` which brings in allot of code analysis packages but allows you to use he `GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges` extension applied on `ITextSnapshot`

```
private IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService GetEditorAdaptersFactoryService()
    {
        IComponentModel componentModel =(IComponentModel)GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        return componentModel.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();
    }   
private Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextView GetTextView()
{
    IVsTextManager textManager = (IVsTextManager)GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
    if (textManager == null)
        return null;
    IVsTextView textView = null;
    textManager.GetActiveView(1, null, out textView);
    if (textView == null)
        return null;
    return GetEditorAdaptersFactoryService().GetWpfTextView(textView);
}

//code to get the doc
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextView textView = GetTextView();
if (textView != null)
{
    SnapshotPoint caretPosition = textView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
    Document document = caretPosition.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
//do stuff with Roslyn Document
}
```

"or am trying to get the current doc id of the selected cs file I right click from the solution explorer."

This is really ugly but what I used from a different SO post (don't remember the author) that does work well.

```
private static bool IsSingleProjectItemSelection(out IVsHierarchy hierarchy, out uint itemid)
    {
        hierarchy = null;
        itemid = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;
        int hr = VSConstants.S_OK;

        var monitorSelection = Package.GetGlobalService( typeof( SVsShellMonitorSelection ) ) as IVsMonitorSelection;
        var solution = Package.GetGlobalService( typeof( SVsSolution ) ) as IVsSolution;
        if (monitorSelection == null || solution == null)
            return false;

        IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect = null;
        IntPtr hierarchyPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr selectionContainerPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            hr = monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection( out hierarchyPtr, out itemid, out multiItemSelect, out selectionContainerPtr );
            if (ErrorHandler.Failed( hr ) || hierarchyPtr == IntPtr.Zero || itemid == VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL)
                return false;
            // multiple items are selected
            if (multiItemSelect != null)
                return false;
            // there is a hierarchy root node selected, thus it is not a single item inside a project
            if (itemid == VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT)
                return false;

            hierarchy = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown( hierarchyPtr ) as IVsHierarchy;
            if (hierarchy == null)
                return false;

            Guid guidProjectID = Guid.Empty;

            if (ErrorHandler.Failed( solution.GetGuidOfProject( hierarchy, out guidProjectID ) ))
                return false;

            // if we got this far then there is a single project item selected
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (selectionContainerPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.Release( selectionContainerPtr );

            if (hierarchyPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.Release( hierarchyPtr );
        }
    }

IVsHierarchy hierarchy = null;
                uint itemid = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;
                if (!IsSingleProjectItemSelection(out hierarchy, out itemid))
                    return;
                string itemFullPath = null;
                ((IVsProject)hierarchy).GetMkDocument(itemid, out itemFullPath);
                if (itemFullPath.EndsWith(".cs"))
```

Comment: Looks like a potential solution for me. I'll try it out. Will there be a problem should the solution has a large numbers of projects? Performance wise?

Comment: Because it starts at the cursor and works its way out to the project it should not matter how many projects there are, but that depends on how the API works underneath as well so I can't say make promises.

Comment: Thanks- This helped me with my current solutions. I am new to Extension development and the tip with `GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges` helped me to get the Analysis package installed that gets me the document File Names! OMG.. its a bit crazy but finally after many hours you helped me figure it out +1 (I edited your answer to include the dependency)